# How can I use global variables with dlopen?

Tags: c

I want to create a program that reads a static library using dlfcn.h, in Main.c, there will be a variable called a which is global, and I want to access it through the library using extern int a and using it in a function, but at the same time do this and execute it, dlerror returns a non-null value, an error.

Main.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 37;

int main(){
  void *lib = dlopen("./libA.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if(dlerror() != NULL){
    printf("Error loading library.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  void (*f)() = dlsym(lib, "fun");
  dlclose(lib);
  return 0;
}
```

Lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;

void fun(){
  printf("%i\n", a);
}
```

I tryed to use -fPIC argument in gcc but it doesn't works. De

Comment: You can bridge from the dynamic library into whatever loads it via functions, but I'm not sure you can bridge a global in some arbitrary executable into a library which has never heard of such an executable. Maybe you need an intermediate library to manage setting(s) like this, then both the loaded library and your main executable can use the same library, and by extension, value.

Comment: Perhaps if you actually printed what `dlerror()` returns, the actual error message, you'd have a better idea of what the problem is?

Comment: Any reason you can't make `fun` take an `int *` and send the address in from `main`?

Comment: The docs say "Any global symbols in the executable that were placed into its
       dynamic symbol table by ld(1) can also be used to resolve
       references in a dynamically loaded shared object."  So I expect what you are trying to do to work -- or at least, to be work*able*.